# Cant change app icon. (Studio picks it up from the xml file) there is

Tags: java, android

I have updated all ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round images with the one i wanna use. However there are XML files that points to the default image. How can i make android studio use the pics i have provided ?

This is the manifest:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

[image: XML files]

Answer (score 0):

Those XML files are for adaptive icons.

Adaptive icons are those which change their shape (circle, rounded square, etc) automatically according to launcher's settings. They are supported from Android 8.0 onwards.

As mentioned by @Micer, you can read more at: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

Create/Replace launcher icons as follows:

- File > New > Image Asset
- choose 'Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)'
- Supply your base icon, save as `ic_launcher`
- Save (or replace) icons.

If you choose not to use adaptive icons at all, you can delete those XML files.

Comment: Can you explain to me the difference between the adaptive and then one i have provided ? And also, i have the complete image and the image asset studio asks for both a foreground and a background one.

Answer (score 0):

Android is now using adaptive icons and you need to generate them. Docs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

In Android Studio, select **File** -> **New** -> **Image Asset** and select "Launcher Icons (Adaptive and Legacy)".

In short, you need 2 input assets:

- background - 1 image in PNG format, can be just a simple square with gradient, no rounded corners etc.
- foreground - 1 image in PNG format, logo with transparent background

Both assets in high enough resolution, 1024 x 1024 px is ok.

Comment: So i have to create the icon myself from now on, and those images i provided are for when i dont want to use an adaptive icon ?

Comment: You can still use the "old" method and provide the icon, but it will look weird/different on some phones with Android 8+.